# Deadline support in Google Calendar

Tags: web-apps, time-management, calendar, google-calendar

It appears to me that Google Calendar events can consist of either an event which lasts a whole day (hence a specific date and time is given), or an event which may span several seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, etc..., but sometimes all we want is to enter a deadline. Sure, a deadline is not necessarily just one date, but it could also be two dates, since any assignment to which a deadline is attached is given out on a specific day. So perhaps it would just make sense to create a Google Calendar instance called Deadlines and use both dates.

**QUESTION:** Is there any deadline extension that shows on Google Calendar (on PC and Android at least), and uses Google Calendar cloud service to store its data (or at least to back it up to the cloud)?